# Jquery Slidetoggle each function (opened/closed)

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, toggleclass

I have the following piece of jquery. Which basically is a content slider, that when I click on a link with an id of `slick-toggle1` it will slide down the matching content `slickbox1`. The same with `slick-toggle2 --> slickbox2` etcetc.

```
$('a.clickdown').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var index = $this.attr('id').match(/(\d+)$/, '');
      var number = parseInt(index[1]);
      $this.click(function() {
          $('#slickbox' + number).slideToggle(400);
          $this.toggleClass('opened').blur();
         return false;
     });
});
```

At the moment as I click through the individual links the corresponding areas will stack. However what I want to achieve is: when I click on say `slick-toggle2` it will display `slickbox2` but hide the others (so `slickbox1` & `slickbox3`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, which will find all elements which id start with slickbox and slide those up.

```
$('a.clickdown').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var index = $this.attr('id').match(/(\d+)$/, '');
    var number = parseInt(index[1]);
    $this.click(function() {
        $('[id^=slickbox]').slideUp(); // This does the magic.
        $('#slickbox' + number).stop(true, true).slideToggle(400);
        $this.toggleClass('opened').blur();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: ok just to add to this is how would i make it so that if i were to click on an open element it would close it instead of reopening it?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `hidable` class to every link you want to hide, eg `<a class="clickdown hidable">` then in the click function, do `$(".hidable").hide();`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are searching for the **jquery accordion** : http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion . This jQuery plug-in does this automaticaly. Slides the one you click on open. And closes the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Add a call to `#slickbox`'s parent (lets call it `slick_parent`) and `slideUp` all child divs, and then slideDown the desired box :

```
$this.click(function() {
    $('#slick_parent > div').slideUp();
    $('#slickbox' + number).slideToggle(400);
    $this.toggleClass('opened').blur();
    return false;
});
```